# Goroutines don't reply after a while

Tags: go, amazon-sqs, goroutine

I initialize a *goroutine* as a worker, to continuously receive messages from *aws sqs*.

The worker works like a charm until there are no message receive from *sqs queue*. The worker seem to lost (unresponsive).

Is the problem relative to GC? Anyone encounter this problem?

Here is simple code https://play.golang.org/p/CuyvUy7b_Sf .

**Updated**:

```
func main() {
    // Init router
    // Handling some APIs
    // ...
}

func userWorker() {
    sqsClient := getSqsClient()
    for {
        result, err := sqsClient.ReceiveMessage(&sqs.ReceiveMessageInput{
            QueueUrl:            aws.String(queueURL),,
            MaxNumberOfMessages: aws.Int64(1),
            MessageAttributeNames: aws.StringSlice([]string{
                "All",
            }),
            WaitTimeSeconds: aws.Int64(1), // wait for seconds
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Unable to receive message from sqs queue  %v.", err)
            continue
        }

        if len(result.Messages) > 0 {
            if result.Messages[0].MessageAttributes["payload"] != nil {
                // extract payload
                messagePayload := result.Messages[0].MessageAttributes["payload"].BinaryValue
                var payload schema.UsersWorkerPayload
                err = msgpack.Unmarshal(messagePayload, &payload)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Error when msgpack decodes payload %v", err)
                    continue
                }

                // get devices tokens from userIDs
                tokenIDs, err := db.GetTokenIdByUsers(payload.UserIds)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("userWorker error GetTokenIdByUsers %v", err)
                    continue
                }
                if len(tokenIDs) == 0 {
                    log.Println("Could not get token ID.")
                    continue
                }

                results, err := fcm.PushToTokenIDs(tokenIDs, payload.Payload)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("userWorker PushToTokenIDs error %v", err)
                    continue
                } else {
                    // delete message if everything is ok
                    err = mrsqs.DeleteMessage(config.UserQueueName, result.Messages[0].ReceiptHandle)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Printf("Error when delete sqs message %v", err)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func init() {
    go userWorker()
}
```

Comment: Shared code looks good. Make sure you do not exit from loop (continue) or panic without logging that event. Share more code if that is still not resolved.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that the goroutine is irresponsive? Does it mean that when messages appear in the queue, the worker doesn't handle them anymore?

Comment: Yes. @AndreyDyatlov

Comment: From the example, it's hard to understand, which part of it is just a sketch or simplification, and which is essential. For example, if the program would compile it exits immediately after printing the greeting as the `main()` function doesn't wait till the goroutine is complete.
Another suspicious thing is that you are starting the worker in the `init()` function.
Could you please try to come up with a minimum viable example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, the worker seem to be freezed after a while, It mean that the goroutine already complete the initialization. I updated example here https://play.golang.org/p/wEVHmajqlCF. Note that I didn't get any logs

Comment: All questions must be complete without following links. Please put the relevant portion of code directly into the question.

Comment: Got it, I updated relevant code in question above.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but I can guarantee you it's nothing to do with GC.

Comment: What is the are the workers actually _doing_ when you say it they are unresponsive? If there are goroutines, then you can see their stacks. If they're blocked then you can see where in their stack traces. If they're executing code, you can see that in a profile.

Comment: Sadly, I didn't track stack traces or profile, the problem is hard to reproduce. I am keeping invest into it.

Answer (score 0):

This program will exit immediately after the `fmt.Println("Hello, playground")` command is complete. You can use the [wait group](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) or a channel to keep the goroutine running.

```
func main() {
    go userWorker()
    c := make(chan struct{})
    <-c
}

func userWorker() {
...
}
```

Comment: In fact, I have a simple server that handle some APIs, so that *userWorker* will not exit immediately. Sorry for the lack of clarification.